# TSQL: How to ensure one ID has multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to ensure each `IncidentID` has 2 specific `ResponseCodes` (201 AND 204).  How do I identify an `IncidentID` that does not have both 201 AND 204, as seen in the pics below?

**Data Set**

[image]

**What I'm trying to identify in the data set**

[image]

**Desired result set:**

[image]

**SQL Fiddle won't work for me, but the test code is below:**

```
CREATE TABLE DIS (
IncidentID NUMERIC,
ResponseCode NUMERIC,
ResponseCodeDescription varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO DIS (IncidentID, ResponseCode, ResponseCodeDescription)
VALUES
      ( '999888', '201', 'OSS'), 
      ( '999888', '204', 'Long Term OSS'),
      ( '888777', '201', 'OSS'),
      ( '888777', '204', 'Long Term OSS'),
      ( '777666', '204', 'Long Term OSS'),
      ( '555444', '201', 'OSS'),
      ( '555444', '204', 'Long Term OSS')

SELECT 
    IncidentID
 ,  ResponseCode
 ,  ResponseCodeDescription
FROM DIS
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IncidentID
FROM DIS
WHERE ResponseCode IN (201,204)
GROUP BY IncidentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ResponseCode) < 2
```

This query will select `IncidentID` values having a `ResponseCode` value equal to either `201` or `204` but not both.

Comment: Why the case expression ?

Comment: Thank you @Giorgos Betsos! Your example and explanation in particular are much appreciated!

Comment: Will this also work if there are more than one Response Code I'm trying to ensure has the 201 code?  For example, I need to ensure every single code listed has a 201 code that goes with it.  So if I have 205, 206, 207, 208 codes, do I just add those the WHERE clause, like this?  (201, 204, 205 etc).

Comment: @JM1 You want to ensure that `IncidentID` has `201` and nothing else?

Comment: No, I need to know all IncidentID's that don't have a 201.

Comment: @JM1 Then use `COUNT(CASE WHEN ResponseCode = 201 THEN 1 END) = 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107646/discussion-between-jm1-and-giorgos-betsos).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses like this:

```
SELECT IncidentID
FROM yourtable
WHERE ResponseCode IN (201,204)
GROUP by IncidentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IncidentID) < 2
```

Comment: And if there is more then 2 incidentID ? Or duplicates for that matter

Comment: Thanks @Rahul.  I saw you edited the question.  Did I enter the data incorrectly?  Is there a better way to enter the data so someone doesn't have to edit it?

Comment: @JM1:- I edited it since it was not formatted initially. but later on since you have formatted it correctly it looks fine now :)

Comment: @sagi:- Yes then in that case we have to use `DISTINCT` which makes it similar to Giorgos Betsos answer. Didnt thought about duplication initially. :)